# STRING COMPARSION FLASH AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I got an input textfield in the UI.

When user key in "GIRAFFEEE", "GIRAFEAAA" OR "GIRAFFE123" and submit. The score value should be 0. However it returns 1.

How do I compare case sensitive string correctly?

```
qns1 = qns1_txt.text.toLowerCase();
qns1Ans = "giraffe"
//.toLowerCase();
if (qns1 == qns1Ans)
{
    score = 1;
}
else
{
    score = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, please, place `trace(qns1)` right after `qns1 = qns1_txt.text.toLowerCase();` string and show output.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. when I key in "GIRAFFEEE" the value is converted to lower case "giraffeee". if "giraffeee" == "giraffe" score should be 0. but my score is 1.

Comment: Problem is exaclty in workaround of your code. Because "giraffeee" can't be equivalent "giraffe" even in flash runtime. Can you show more code or get us simplified demo?

Comment: Have you typed those variables as being String? The only way I can think of this behaviour is when you typed them as being Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you test following:

```
var correct:String = "giraffe";
var userAns:String = "giraffeaaaa";

trace(correct == userAns);//false - as expected
```

it means that string comparison works:)

I assume that your test code is in the CHANGE event of the textfield which may result in false positive as user may type part of correct answer, I think you should do a function:

```
function validate()
{
    qns1 = qns1_txt.text.toLowerCase();
    qns1Ans = "giraffe"

    score = 0;
    if(qns1 == qns1Ans)
    {
        score = 1;
    }
}
```

and call it when user will hit submit, you could also compare the length of strings but equal operator will do just fine.